# There is a fast way to use Clojure vectors as matrices?

Tags: performance, clojure, profiling

I am trying to use Clojure to process images and I would like to represent images using Clojure data structures. Basically, my first approach was using a vector of vectors and `mapv` to operate over each pixel value and return a new image representation with the same data structure. However, some basic operations are taking too much time.

Using Jvisual profiler, I got the results showed below. Somebody could give me a tip to improve the performance? I can give more details if it is necessary, but maybe just looking at the costs of `seq` and `next` someone can have a good guess.

[image: Profiling results of an operation over the vector of vectors.]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried the new [core.matrix](https://github.com/mikera/matrix-api) library?  It's pretty new but they are trying to come up with a general scheme for matrix manipulations and it might be worth a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really think that you should use arrays of primitives for this.  Clojure has array support built-in, even though it's not highlighted, and it's for cases just like this, where you have a high volume of numerical data.

Any other approach, vectors, even java collections will result in all of your numbers being boxed individually, which is very wasteful.  Arrays of primitives (int, double, byte, whatever is appropriate) don't have this problem, and that's why they're there.  People feel shy about using arrays in clojure, but they're there for a reason, and this is it.  And it'll be good protable clojure code -- int-array works in both jvm clojure and clojure-script.

Try arrays and benchmark.

Comment: better would be to use a Clojure library that wraps the handling of primitive arrays for you, e.g. vectorz-clj

Answer (score 7):

You should check out **[core.matrix](https://github.com/mikera/matrix-api)** and associated libraries for anything to do with matrix computation. core.matrix is a general purpose Clojure API for matrix computation, supporting multiple back-end implementations.

Clojure's persistent data structures are great for most purposes, but are really not suited for fast processing of large matrices. The main problems are:

- *Immutability*: usually a good thing, but can be a killer for low level code where you need to do things like accumulate results in a mutable array for performance reasons.
- *Boxing*: Clojure data structures generally box results (as java.lang.Double etc.) which adds a lot of overhead compared to using primitives
- *Sequences*: traversing most Clojure data structures as sequences involved the creation of temporary heap objects to hold the sequence elements. Normally not a problem, but when you are dealing with large matrices it becomes problematic.

The related libraries that you may want to look at are:

- **[vectorz-clj](https://github.com/mikera/vectorz-clj)** : a very fast matrix library that works as a complete core.matrix implementation. The underlying code is pure Java but with a nice Clojure wrapper. I believe it is currently the fastest way of doing general purpose matrix computation in Clojure without resorting to native code. Under the hood, it uses arrays of Java primitives, but you don't need to deal with this directly.
- **[Clatrix](https://github.com/tel/clatrix)**: another fast matrix library for Clojure which is also a core.matrix implementation. Uses JBLAS under the hood.
- **[image-matrix](https://github.com/clojure-numerics/image-matrix)** : represents a Java BufferedImage as a core.matrix implementation, so you can perform matrix operations on images. A bit experimental right now, but should work for basic use cases
- **[Clisk](https://github.com/mikera/clisk)** : a library for procedural image processing. Not so much a matrix library itself, but very useful for creating and manipulating digital images using a Clojure-based DSL.

Depending on what you want to do, the best approach may be to use image-matrix to convert the images into vectorz-clj matrices and do your processing there. Alternatively, Clisk might be able to do what you want out of the box (it has a lot of ready-made filters / distortion effects etc.)

**Disclaimer**: I'm the lead developer for most of the above libraries. But I'm using them all myself for serious work, so very willing to vouch for their usefulness and help fix any issues you find.

Comment: Nice! I really liked the idea and I'll check this out! However, at least for now, I would like to work with integers matrices too.

Answer (score 1):

Clojure's [Transients](http://clojure.org/transients) offer a middle ground between full persistence and no persistence like you would get with a standard java array. This allows you to build the image using fast mutate-in-place opperations (which are limited to the current thread) and then call `persistent!` to convert it in constante time to a proper persistent structure for manipulation in the rest of the program

It looks like you are also seeing a lot of overhead from working with sequences over the contents of the image, if transients don't make enough of a difference you may want to next consider using normal java arrays and structure the accesses to directly access the array elements.

Comment: Under the hood, `mapv` uses transients to generate new vectors. So, in this sense, I don't have almost any improvements to do. Java arrays seems to be a better idea.